# Unable to start httpd CentOS 7

Tags: centos, apache-httpd

When trying to start httpd "systemctl start httpd" the following is returned

```
Job for httpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

The command "systemctl status httpd.service" shows no specific errors

```
httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: 
disabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2021-07-12 16:35:43 IDT; 2min 48s ago
Docs: man:httpd(8)
man:apachectl(8)
Process: 1960 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, 
status=1/FAILURE)
Main PID: 1960 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jul 12 16:35:43 testvm.am.com systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP 
Server...
Jul 12 16:35:43 testvm.am.com systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process 
exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jul 12 16:35:43 testvm.am.com systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache 
HTTP Server.
Jul 12 16:35:43 testvm.am.com systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered 
failed state.
Jul 12 16:35:43 testvm.am.com systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
```

Whats is possible to do?

Comment: The httpd log files are under /var/log/httpd. They should help pinpointing the problem.

Comment: Yes, it shows a problem "AH02203: Init: Private key not found". That means there is an issue with "SSLCertificateKeyFile" in file /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf?

Comment: All errors solved in "ssl.conf" file. httpd starts, but connecting via https shows "This site can’t be reached... ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED"

Comment: So, you fixed the original problem but are now running into a different error? All I can do is repeat my suggestion to consult the log files.